# Error when installing react navigation packages in react native Android

Tags: react-native

Im currently doing a course in udemy about react-native and one of the contents requires me to install react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context. However when installing "npm install @react-navigation/stack" and run the app (metro) i get this error :

[image]

Is there any fix? thanks

Comment: Can you paste the first few lines of your MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow react-navigation documentation([react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)).
Also, ensure that you have installed the required libraries.

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

If you have npm use this:

```
npm install -save @react-navigation/native react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Install above libraries and then install stack navigation.

```
yarn add @react-navigation/stack
```

for npm:

```
npm install --save @react-navigation/stack
```